# Is D.Va's ultimate affected by Mercy's damage boost?

Tags: overwatch

I know that D.Va's ultimate negates Zenyata's discord orb but does it get buffed by Mercy's damage boost if she's using it on you before you activate your self-destruct or does the buff stay on D.Va herself after you launch the mech?

It's not really a question of whether it's useful or not, since Self-Destruct will kill anyone the blast wave touches, but I'm just interested if D.Va's mech is essentially a separate entity when it comes to buffs.

Comment: I want to add a note that this is *very* important in Total Mayhem arcade gamemode, as many heroes can survive the explosion by simple facetanking. Mercy buffing a friendly D.Va will ensure that enemy D.Va will lose her mech to the buffed self-destruct, an unbuffed one often allows her to escape and get healed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long answer: I tried in a custom game with regular damage and health settings, and my results were simple:

- At the center of the explosion, Self-Destruct will one-shot any unbuffed player character, regardless of health, which means it deals 1000 damage or more.
- At a few meters, I managed to have a Roadhog survive the explosion with a little over 100 health, which means the damage has a fall-off based on the distance from the center of the explosion.
- At the same distance, with Mercy's damage buff, the same Roadhog died to the explosion (I may have positioned it a little off the original position, as I didn't use a ground mark - in hindsight, writing this now, I should have, and maybe will test again later).
- I had Mercy's beam fall off one try (because I think it normally gets reapplied instantly to pilot-D.va when she comes out of the meka) and the damage boost didn't apply, and Roadhog survived. Which means the damage boost is applied at the moment of the **explosion**, not of the eject. So only if Mercy is buffing D.va when the mech explodes, the damage boost is applied.

I took liberty and tried with a couple more "external-based" ultimates, and came to conclusion that it works with most of them, but not with Junkrat's Rip-Tire for some reason, which is probably a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the blast radius thing and showing that the buff can be useful for killing players farther from the center!

Comment: When using Rip-Tire, does the Healing or Damage Buff meter from Mercy appear at the side of the screen?

Comment: In-fact it does not - the whole interface changes to a new Rip-Tire-based interface, with it's own health value, for instance. That's probably why Mercy's buff doesn't affect it.

Comment: @fcm can you target the rip tire with Mercy? If so it'd be worth testing. I wouldn't be surprised if you couldn't target it at all though.

Comment: @CaptainMan I believe I've tried this, it doesn't seem to work. You can't even shift to it, the prompt does not show up.

Comment: Couldn't you have just used Reinhardt's shield to test all this, since it has 2000 health?

Comment: I think you need to buff the rip tire itself (the 100 hp thing that no one shoots) to increase its dmg

Comment: @KimMinseo you can't buff the rip tire itself; Mercy can't target it.

Comment: @fcm so for buffing the ult, Mercy's beam has to be on the meka itself when it detonates? Isn't there a "target priority" setting in the game somewhere that changes how readily Mercy's beam switches, so maybe turning it down would allow you to keep the beam on the meka after D.Va jumps out instead of it trying to flip to pilot-D.Va?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to the first answer, yesy, with damage boost from Mercy, the damage of the autodestruct go from 1000 damage to 1300 damage (minus damage falloff)

And yes, the damage boost is effective only when the damage is applied (i.e. throw a rocket, get damage boosted before the rocket hit and it will beneficiate from that. Do it the other way around and it will not.), so boost D.va when the MEKA explodes.