# What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?

Tags: overwatch

What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?

We already know that [D.va's ultimate can be damage boosted by Mercy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269472/181240), but are there other ultimates that can be damage boosted by Mercy? Can all ultimates be damage boosted by Mercy?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer But that's a different question?

Comment: The answer is the same.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Are the questions the same?

Comment: I already answered that. Like you already answered your question elsewhere. Why not make it a generic "What is buffed by Mercy?" instead?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer And what about this? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost Did you leave a VTC vote there as well?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Sorry, but you still haven't answered both questions. An answer that covers another question does not make two questions equal, shocking enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm answering the question as to which ultimates *can* be buffed, not which ones *should* be.

- Bastion's Tank mode
- D.Va's Self-Destruct
- Genji's Dragonblade
- Hanzo's Dragonstrike ([As confirmed by Kim below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269542/what-ultimates-can-be-damage-boosted-by-mercy/269652#comment377704_269652))
- McCree's Deadeye (Lethal damage achieved faster)
- Pharah's Barrage
- Reaper's Death Blossom
- Reinhardt's Earthshatter
- Roadhog's Whole Hog
- Soldier 76's Tactical Visor
- Winston's Primal Rage

I've left out the following as I'm not sure:

- Mei's Blizzard (The value of this ult is not in it's damage anyway)
- Tracer's Pulse Bomb

Comment: I can confirm that Hanzo ult damage can be buffed, I've gotten offensive assists by buffing Hanzo while he ulted.

Comment: Deadeye can be buffed, the circles grow smaller faster.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Shaffanhoon's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269542/what-ultimates-can-be-damage-boosted-by-mercy/269652#269652), I've put together a more complete list of which ultimates are affected by Mercy's damage buff.

### Ultimates affected by Mercy's damage boost

- ***Bastion's*** Tank Mode
- ***D.Va's*** Self-Destruct<sup>1</sup> ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472))
- ***Genji's*** Dragonblade
- ***Hanzo's*** Dragonstrike
- ***McCree's*** Deadeye<sup>2</sup> ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/))
- ***Pharah's*** Rocket Barrage
- ***Reaper's*** Death Blossom
- ***Reinhardt's*** Earthshatter
- ***Roadhog's*** Whole Hog<sup>3</sup>
- ***Soldier 76's*** Tactical Visor
- ***Tracer's*** Pulse Bomb ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/d3qi9lf/))
- ***Winston's*** Primal Rage<sup>3</sup>

### Ultimates that stack with Mercy's damage boost

- ***Ana's*** Nano Boost
- ***Orisa's*** Supercharge

### Ultimates NOT affected by Mercy's damage boost

- ***Junkrat's*** RIP-Tire ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/))
- ***Torbjörn's*** Molten Core

### Unknown

- ***D.Va's*** Call Mech
- ***Mei's*** Blizzard
- ***Zarya's*** Graviton Surge

### N/A (Ultimates that don't do any damage)

- ***Lucio's*** Sound Barrier
- ***Mercy's*** Resurrect
- ***Sombra's*** EMP
- ***Symmetra's*** Teleporter and Shield Generator
- ***Widowmaker's*** Infra-Sight
- ***Zenyatta's*** Transcendence

---

#### Sources

- [Reddit - Mercy's damage boost works on almost everything as long as the boost is applied when the target RECEIVES the damage](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost_everything_as/)
- [Reddit - Myself and some friends tested some more Mercy damage boost myths!](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4m2fgj/myself_and_some_friends_tested_some_more_mercy/)
- [What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269542/what-ultimates-can-be-damage-boosted-by-mercy/269652#269652)
- [Is D.Va's ultimate affected by Mercy's damage boost?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472)

#### See Also

- [What projectiles can Genji deflect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309635/181240)
- [What Attacks Can D.Va's Shield Block (or Not Block)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309712/181240)
- [What do damage buffs affect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309724/181240)

#### Notes

*<sup>1</sup>Beam must be on mechless D.Va to boost explosion damage. See [Is D.Va's ultimate affected by Mercy's damage boost?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/is-d-vas-ultimate-affected-by-mercys-damage-boost/269472#269472).

<sup>2</sup>Deadeye's red circle and skull indicators will reflect the damage buff. Indicators revert to normal damage if buff is removed before firing.

<sup>3</sup>Knockback is not affected.*

Comment: Wrong question, try this https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272006/how-does-mercys-damage-buff-work

Comment: Molten Core doesn't deal damage, listing it is pointless. The N/A section is as well.

Answer (score -2):

Any damage source can be buffed by Mercy, except in the case of it involving another entity, like turrets, Widowmaker's mine and Junkrat's trap (the mine can be buffed however).

D.Va's Self-Destruct is a special case : Mercy can't actually target the MEKA except if she's already targeting D.Va when she activates it. It's usually useless though.

Comment: Widowmaker's mine and Junkrat's trap can be damage boosted by buffing the Widowmaker/Junkrat when they detonate.